# Full screen HTML5 Video Background goes off page

Tags: css, html, video

Currently working on a site where I want to add a full screen video background like that of Airbnb.

My issue is that the video always goes off the page. This happens when I have the width set to `cover`. My solution for this is of course was to set it to `100%` but this then ruins the height for the responsive design. Setting it to `auto` doesn't seam to work either.

Wrapping the video in anther div doesn't work.

I tried having different styling for the @media quires but the issue remains where the video stretches off the page.

I looked around and came across [this.](http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video) Seams to be what I have yet mine still goes off.

CSS

```
video#bgvid { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

HTML

```
<video autoplay loop poster="bg.png" id="bgvid">
    <source src="video/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The alternative is to use a js but that's a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you gave you are missing the `background` properties which is going to show a static background image in case the video won't load and to `cover` the whole page. And you have to change  your `position: absolute` to `position:fixed` otherwise it will create a overflow

see a working snippet below:

#### Snippet

```css
#bg { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1600/900) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop poster="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" id="bg">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

As mentioned on that link which you are following:

> **Dealing With Mobile**
>
> Displaying the fullscreen background video on mobile devices presents
>   several challenges:
>
> - Most mobile platforms (iOS in particular) will refuse to autoplay HTML5 video to avoid potentially ruinous data charges.
> - In such cases the video will be displayed with an embedded play button, which in turn...
> - ...may capture touches on the device, locking out links that may be in the content on top of the video.
>
> While it is possible to feature-detect support for video autoplay with
>   JavaScript (a technique I will cover in a future article), the easiest
>   solution is to use a media query that switches off the video entirely
>   on smaller screens, substituting the placeholder image in the
>   background

Which you can add by using this @media query:

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1600/900) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { /*or max-device-width*/
  html {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1600/900) #000 no-repeat center center fixed;
  }
  #bg {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop poster="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" id="bg">
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Ya, I'm aware of the background image but that shouldn't effect the size. I didn't add the mobile play buttons on purpose and again, that doesn't have an effect on the video width. I also purposely wanted to add an overflow for text so the absolute is no mistake. It's likely the issue the issue though.

Comment: Ya it is likely the issue for sure. if you want to add text, create a wrapper which is going to be `relative` and then text which going to be `absolute`, the you have to play around with `z-index` If you want I can update my answer based on that "need add to text"

Comment: Tried this but the video then ends up filling the background of the entire page.

Comment: And that's not what you want? I thought that was what you were trying to do

Comment: Don't want it to fill the entire page (header to footer). I just want the top part to have a full screen video. Take a look at [Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com/). Apologizes for not being clear enough.

Comment: @Minymina Airbnb is using a jquery plugin called [hero slider](https://codyhouse.co/gem/hero-slider/)

Comment: Hero slider video or Hero slider images? If you're on a local domain like Airbnb.ie its an image slideshow but on Airbnb.com, its a video. Regardless, can I replicate that with CSS?

Comment: @Minymina take a look at [this](https://codyhouse.co/demo/hero-slider/index.html)

Comment: I'm going to switch to hero now that I know what they're using. I'm just curious to know if it's still possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change Position `absolute` to `fixed`

```css
video#bgvid { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop poster="polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: So just copy-paste the content from link OP posted in OP's question without further explanation?

Comment: But I want to add an overflow. Is there an alternative workaround?